# How would i resume the last viewed activity after the user has been closed the application?

Tags: java, android

How would i resume the last viewed activity after the user has been closed the application. It is like, If the user open the application, the first activity will appear and when the user click the button it will proceed to the next activity, if he close the application and open again it will still show the last viewed activity. how would i do that? please help me.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried to use `onSaveInstanceState`? See on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use sharedpreferences. And in every activity you open, you have to put a value on your sharedpreference so that if you open again your application it will check the value of your shared preference then compare it, call the activity that fits the value you got. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to track his last activity then, keep it in a database and whenever he returns, look up his last  activty in the database...the other way is cookies but not adviseable ....

Answer (score 0):

Place this below line  in `AndroidManifest.xml` for your activities in `<activity/>`.

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```