# Opening the same activity in application after the app is destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to open the same activity which the user was using before the app was quit or destroyed.
How Can I do that?
Please help....

Comment: how many acivities in your application?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311054/how-would-i-resume-the-last-viewed-activity-after-the-user-has-been-closed-the-a